# Getting Google Earth Plugin to work using OpenGeo suite-sdk

Tags: google-earth, boundless-suite

I am learning to make a web GIS using OpenGeo Suite-SDK. I have been trying to get the google earth plugin to work but I still fail to make it. I read from http://dev.horizon.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/sdk-api/lib/plugins/GoogleEarth.html, that it can work if portalItems of gxp.Viewer is set up in certain way.

Where should I put portalItems?

Should I replace items: with portalItems: ?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply change the `portalConfig` in app.js:

```
portalConfig: {
    layout: "border",
    region: "center",

    // by configuring items here, we don't need to configure portalItems
    // and save a wrapping container
    items: [{
        id: "centerpanel",
        xtype: "panel",
        layout: "card",
        region: "center",
        activeItem: 0,
        border: false,
        items: [
            "mymap", {
                xtype: 'gxp_googleearthpanel',
                mapPanel: "map"
            }
        ]
    }, {
        id: "westpanel",
        xtype: "container",
        layout: "fit",
        region: "west",
        width: 200
    }],
    bbar: {id: "mybbar"}
},
```